# Asp.net Core Load Assembly

Tags: c#, dll, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-assembly

I am tring to load some .dll files from a folder:

```
    var fileNames = Directory
        .GetFiles(path, "*.dll", searchOption);
    var assemblyNames = fileNames
        .Select(AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName);

    List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    foreach (AssemblyName assemblyName in assemblyNames)
    {
        assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(assemblyName));
    }
```

But somehow the assembly cannot be loaded:
`FileNotFoundException, Could not load file or assembly [...] The system cannot find the file specified.`

How is this possible, because the file is definitely there?

I can provide additional information, if you need more background.

Comment: In the debug is `fileNames` populated?

Comment: Yes, its an array of string with the first and single entry: "Uploads\\TestPlugin.dll"

Answer (score 3):

With these using statements:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
```

Try this:

```
var myAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(pathTodll);
```

Answer (score 0):

To load a assembly from a file it is easier to use the Assembly.LoadFrom() function. In your application is would look like:

```
var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll", searchOption);
```

`List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
    assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName));
}`

[Edit]

If you are attempting to load the assemblies for later use in the application (e.g. you have reference to the assembly in Visual Studio), it is recommend that you implement the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event. The AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event will fire when an assembly cannot be found and needs to be loaded. At that time you can provide the AppDomain an assembly in a different file location.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I get the following error: 'Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'LoadFrom'. Where can I find that method?

Comment: The LoadFrom method is a built-in part of the .NET Framework. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But it's not part of asp.net core framework (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Reflection/ref/System.Reflection.cs)? I don't have the reference to the assembly, the dlls should be added during runtime.

Comment: @jasdefer in .NET Core, you'd have to use `AssemblyLoadContext` to load assemblies. API docs for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext#System_Runtime_Loader_AssemblyLoadContext_LoadFromAssemblyPath_System_String_

Comment: @Pranav I get the same error with: `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyName);`

Comment: Have you trried using `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath`? `LoadFromAssemblyName` requires the Assembly to be in the probing path.