# .net core does not pick assemblies from Base directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have requirement where types to be loaded will be specified in configuration file, in .net framework we used a config entry like below in config file-

```
"PaasLogger": "HsopPaas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

and use method like below -

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(configuration["PaasLogger"]);
```

now if HsopPaas.dll is in base directory .net framework can pick this up and load
In .net core this does not work and i get FileNotFoundException, according to .net core this is by [design](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/11498)
But what shall we do now that is not clear to me how can i tell .net core to load from Base Directory?

Comment: where are you executing this command? `var assembly = Assembly.Load(configuration["PaasLogger"]);`, In a controller ?

Comment: how will this impact? we do it in startup class.

Comment: because in a controller you must inject IHostingEnvironment, in startup it is already injected

Comment: how IhostingEnvironment can help here?

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope it answers your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the path to assembly, it gets rather easy :

With these using statements:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
```

Try this:

```
var myAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(pathTodll);
```

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920892/asp-net-core-load-assembly)

**Loading all assemblies from root folder :**

Get base directory of your app and load all your `.dll` files from there:

In `Configure` method of `startup.cs` :

```
string appPath = env.ContentRootPath; //Application Base Path
List<Assembly> allAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();

foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(appPath , "*.dll"))
    allAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(dll));
```

Comment: i want .net core to probe in base directory , this will make only that dll to load what if there is a depenecy of this dll on another dll that will cause an issue here, untill i load that dependency as well